# Native protractor test example not running

Tags: angularjs, node.js, selenium, protractor

I'm new to protractor and after installing everything, I tried to run the test example that protractor provides you to test if everything works fine. Apparently, it doesn't.

Here are a few infos of the versions I'm using:

node v6.11.3 |
npm v3.10.10 |
java 1.8 |
selenium webdriver 3.5 |
chrome browser 60.0 |
protractor 5.1.2

This is the conf.js that I'm trying to run:

```
// An example configuration file.
exports.config = {
  directConnect: true,

  // Capabilities to be passed to the webdriver instance.
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
  },

  // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
  framework: 'jasmine',

  // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
  // protractor is called.
  specs: ['example_spec.js'],

  // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
  jasmineNodeOpts: {

     defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000

  }
};
```

The example specification:

```
describe('angularjs homepage', function() {
  it('should greet the named user', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');

    var greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));

    expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });

  describe('todo list', function() {
    var todoList;

    beforeEach(function() {
      browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

      todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    });

    it('should list todos', function() {
      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(2);
      expect(todoList.get(1).getText()).toEqual('build an AngularJS app');
    });

    it('should add a todo', function() {
      var addTodo = element(by.model('todoList.todoText'));
      var addButton = element(by.css('[value="add"]'));

      addTodo.sendKeys('write a protractor test');
      addButton.click();

      expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
      expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the error that it throws:

```
Failures:
1) angularjs homepage should greet the named user
  Message:
    Failed: Timed out waiting for asynchronous Angular tasks to finish after 11 seconds. This may be because the current page is not an Angular application. Please see the FAQ for more details: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular
    While waiting for element with locator - Locator: by.model("yourName")
  Stack:
    ScriptTimeoutError: asynchronous script timeout: result was not received in 11 seconds
      (Session info: chrome=60.0.3112.113)
      (Driver info: chromedriver=2.32.498513 (2c63aa53b2c658de596ed550eb5267ec5967b351),platform=Linux 3.16.0-4-amd64 x86_64)
        at WebDriverError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:27:5)
        at ScriptTimeoutError (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:203:5)
        at Object.checkLegacyResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/error.js:505:15)
        at parseHttpResponse (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:509:13)
        at doSend.then.response (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js:440:13)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)
    From: Task: Protractor.waitForAngular() - Locator: by.model("yourName")
        at Driver.schedule (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:816:17)
        at ProtractorBrowser.executeAsyncScript_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/browser.ts:609:24)
        at angularAppRoot.then (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/browser.ts:643:23)
        at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1366:14)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
        at asyncRun (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2813:27)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:676:7
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:109:7)Error
        at ElementArrayFinder.applyAction_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:482:23)
        at ElementArrayFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:96:21)
        at ElementFinder.(anonymous function) [as sendKeys] (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/lib/element.ts:873:14)
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/example/example_spec.js:5:35)
        at /usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:112:25
        at new ManagedPromise (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1067:7)
        at ControlFlow.promise (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2396:12)
        at schedulerExecute (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:95:18)
        at TaskQueue.execute_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2970:14)
        at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2953:27)
    From: Task: Run it("should greet the named user") in control flow
        at UserContext.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/jasminewd2/index.js:94:19)
    From asynchronous test: 
    Error
        at Suite.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/example/example_spec.js:2:3)
        at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/protractor/example/example_spec.js:1:63)
        at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
        at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
        at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
        at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

3 specs, 1 failure
Finished in 16.136 seconds

[09:34:24] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[09:34:24] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 1 test(s)
[09:34:24] I/launcher - overall: 1 failed spec(s)
[09:34:24] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
```

Apparently, it claims the web page is not an Angular application which cannot be because this test  was an example test by protractor itself to see if everything's working out. I did not write anything of it. 
When running the test chrome opens with the angular web page loaded. It then apparently tries to do "something" but fails and then opens up another page where it writes the string "write a protractor test" into an input label on that page. After that the browser closes.

Does anybody have any idea what is wrong here? I'm starting to get really frustrated. I've been trying to fix this issue for 4 days now.

Comment: when running, did you notice the page: http://www.angularjs.org opened or not?

Comment: Yes, it opened.

Comment: Do you have any browser plugins active? You can try another browser easily if you install a different driver.

Comment: I'm guessing you have some version problems.  Your selenium webdriver is old (3.5 is out), your chrome version is very new.  Update protractor, webdriver, and chromedriver

Comment: Updated everything, selenium version is now 3.5. Problem's still there...
Unfortunately, I have to work with chrome. So changing the browser is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Add allScriptsTimeout in conf.js as Protractor offical site said:
http://www.protractortest.org/#/timeouts

```
specs: ['example_spec.js'],

allScriptsTimeout: 30000,

// Options to be passed to Jasmine.
```

Comment: Inserted allScriptsTimeout, but it didn't change anything. Still getting the same error with a little bit of new text that reads: `1) angularjs homepage should greet the named user
  Message:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
  Stack:
    Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
        at ontimeout (timers.js:386:11)
        at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:250:5)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:214:5)
`

Comment: I tried both on chromedriver 2.31 and 2.32, all pass. from your error log, you used chromedriver 2.32.  what's version of your protractor?

Comment: I'm using version 5.1.2

Answer (score -1):

Try adding below step in spec file

```
      browser.IgnoreSynchronization = true;
```

Comment: she's visiting the angular page.  no need to disable synchronization here